# Can we run a Java program without main method?

Tags: java

For example I want to print statement like -

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

How can the above line be printed on console without using the `public static void main(String arg[]);` in the class.

Comment: No, it can't be.

Comment: No. And next, why?

Comment: Every java program needs a method(function) to store in code .And main method is the entry point of the program so you could put your code in other methods but you need main method to execute that  function.

Comment: @AndrewLi well, you can't run a program, but you can execute simple statement like this without one with Java 9 interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

You will soon be able to do that with `JShell`, this allow you to type java expression in a shell to get the result, without having to compile the program. Here is a simple example from [JShell - Java 9 interpreter (REPL) - Getting Started and Examples](http://jakubdziworski.github.io/java/2016/07/31/jshell-getting-started-examples.html)

```
> jdk-9/bin/jshell -v

jshell> void helloJShell() { System.out.println("hello JShell"); }
|  created method helloJShell()

jshell> helloJShell();
hello JShell
```

You could then simply do

```
jshell> System.out.println("hello");
```

I didn't get time to try this yet but it look as simple as this.

Comment: This! The OP is getting a lot of flak for this question, however, the question is very reasonable! Using JShell is the exact answer to this question. "I want to see what `System.out.println` does without writing a main method". How? JShell!!!

Comment: @flakes this will be a useful tool to learn basic Java, writing a class with a main method was the first step to learn the language, it was not really the easiest as it have some keyword that was only explain later.

Comment: It's useful for more than just beginners! I've been using it for about a year now and find it really handy for a lot of my prototyping. All of what I write is targeted towards a Java 8 environment, but I debug in Java9 using JShell. I can interact with my servers, make live changes to data sets, and much more. It's a shame that Java9 has been so delayed